# Web Scraping Tabelog for budget lunch and dinner

Tags: python, html

This is my first shot at scraping a website after being stuck in tutorial land for months. 
I'm trying to find budget meals for lunch and dinner on Tabelog, but I receive "None" as my output. I've searched on google how to web scrape sites with a price range meter, but they mostly showed scraping price for certain product. I'm lost on how to fix the "None" I get as output.

[Tabelog Scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L63j.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import request
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://tabelog.com/en/tokyo/rstLst/'
r = requests.get(url)
html_page = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

budget_price = soup.find('<span id="js-price-range-min" class="tb-slider-range tb-slider-range--min">¥0</span>')
budget_lunch = soup.find('<div class="search-filter__price-table-time"><input type="radio" name="RdoCosTp" id="RdoCosTp_1" value="1" class="c-radio"><label for="RdoCosTp_1"><i class="gly-b-lunch search-filter__price-gly"></i>Lunch</label></div>')
budget_dinner = soup.find('<div class="search-filter__price-table-time"><input type="radio" name="RdoCosTp" id="RdoCosTp_2" value="2" class="c-radio" checked="checked"><label for="RdoCosTp_2"><i class="gly-b-dinner search-filter__price-gly"></i>Dinner</label></div>')

print(budget_price)
print(budget_lunch)
print(budget_dinner)
```

Any help or how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the link. I've completed online tutorials at datacamp for python up to intermediate python with importing data from web, but seem to get 'None' as my output. I looked at your link, but that shows find 'div' with id. I've tried using this format "("div",{'class':"some text"}), but it brought errors, so I researched and found just copy pasting the "span" or "div" didnt bring an erro, but "None" as the output.

Comment: what are the expected return values please? Are you after min and max as appear to left and right of slider? Only 3 values?

Comment: QHarr, I was after the min values. Was trying to set price for 1000¥, but gave up scraping. I'll give a try for data cleaning instead. Thank you.